# Aggregate query on mysql 8

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have two tables, allowances & salaries,

Allowances table looks like,

```
Id  Title       value
1   Transport   2000
2   Housing     1000
3   Housing     1000
```

The Salaries table,

```
    id  Salary
    1   2000
    2   1000
    3   3000
```

For id's with no *Housing* allowance the value should be considered as 0 for housing and just the salary should be shown. If housing allowance is available, add up salary and housing.

My query is not exactly giving the right output,

```
SELECT 
    s.id,
    CASE
        WHEN t.`Housing` = 0 THEN s.salary
    END AS Salary,
    CASE
        WHEN t.`Housing` <> 0 THEN t.Housing + s.salary
        WHEN t.`Housing` = 0 THEN  s.salary
    END AS SalaryAndHousing
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id,
            CASE
                WHEN Title = 'Housing' THEN value
                WHEN Title <> 'Housing' THEN 0
            END AS 'Housing'
    FROM
        Allowance) t
        JOIN
    Salaries s ON (t.id = s.id);
```

The output of my query is,

```
id  Salary  SalaryAndHousing
1    2000        2000
2    null        2000
3    null        4000
```

It should look like,

```
   id        Salary    SalaryAndHousing
    1         2000          2000 -- 2000 + 0
    2         1000          2000 -- 1000 + 1000
    3         3000          4000 -- 1000 + 3000
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b526a2204aeaba33e755fd90559290e0)

Comment: salary will only be printed when WHEN t.`Housing` = 0 - surely you always want salary..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be pretty simple query:

```
select 
    s.id,
    s.Salary,
    s.Salary + coalesce(a.value, 0) SalaryAndHousing
from Salaries s 
left join Allowance a on a.id = s.id and a.Title = 'Housing'
order by s.id;
```

Try it on [SQLize.online](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=32c06955864ce7db94d8d5fce053c1d0&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: Thank you, but I need two columns not one as shown in my desired result.

Comment: Yep. Updated just now